# HTML iframe with page links

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I know using iframes is not always the best idea, but for my case it makes things easier. I have a website A which contains links to other parts on the same site (using `<a name=...`). I have a seconds site B which has an iframe containing A. Everything works fine, except the page hyperlinks, if you click on them, nothing happens.

Does anyone know if named hyperlinks are even possible in iframe? And if yes how to make them work.

**EDIT:**

Seems like I wasn't clear enough. The file is named test.html (http://www.domain.com/embedded/test.html) and contains a hyperlink at the top

```
<a href="#examples">Examples</a>
```

then somewhere at the end there is a link

```
<a name="examples"></a>
```

So when you click on the top link the page should scroll down to the bottom link. I have a second page (http://www.domain.com/index.html) with the iframe containing test.html. When hovering over the link (inside the iframe), it shows http://www.domain.com/embedded/test.html#examples. I'm not and iframe expert, but this link seems as it would rather redirect to the actual file (to #examples), rather than jumping inside the iframe. As I said before when clicking on the link nothing happens. Just tested in in Chrome and it works. Seems like this is a problem specific to Firefox.

Comment: You can add anchor to your links like yoursite.com/content.html#section_name

Comment: Do you want the iframe to go to other pages on your website when you click on a hyperlink?

Comment: I think you need to post a real codesnippet of that link list, and maybe some anchors too, otherwise answering will be only guessing...

Answer (score 1):

These parts of your question make me smell something: "links to other parts on the same site (using `<a name=...`)" and "named hyperlinks"...

A hyperlink for moving to an other part of the *same* page:

`<a href="#BOOKMARK">Goto BOOKMARK</a>`

And an anchor (bookmark) somewhere else in the *same* page:

`<a name="BOOKMARK"></a>`

These are working in every HTML-document, regardless they were shown in the `iframe`or not.

Comment: Well they work on the normal site, but the moment it is embedded in an iframe is stops working.

Comment: Odd... have you tried `<a href="http://www.domain.com/embedded/test.html#examples">Goto Examples</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I too wanted a link in an embedded page to point to a bookmark in the containing page. But I am not sure if our circumstances are exactly the same.

A local link such as

`<a href="#BOOKMARK">`

will only look for an anchor in the same page as the link, i.e. in the embedded page. An approach such as

`<a href="containing-page.html#BOOKMARK" target="top">`

will only work if your link always references the same containing page. (The target needs to be specified, to display the page outside the iframe.) I am not sure if this will meet your needs.

If you want to re-use a common bookmark name in different containing pages, as I do, the design effectively requires the destination url to be treated as a variable, and that cannot be done using pure HTML. It requires javascript or similar.

It was in fact more elegant for me to add the bookmark link to the containing page, so that I do not need to standardize my bookmark names. This does not even need javascript, just a bit of css.

What I did was to position the bookmark link over the embedded display, so that it looks like it is part of the embedded page. In this example, the iframe is fixed at the top of the page and the bookmark link positioned over its top left corner.

```
<iframe style="position:fixed; left:0pt; top:0pt;" src="embedded-page.html"></iframe>
<div style="position:fixed; left:0pt; top:0pt;">
    <a href="#BOOKMARK">My Bookmark</a>
</div>
```

With a bit of css refinement, this gives some flexibility of layout. For your issue, you may need to stick with javascript.